# Are there any select_tag like RoR on Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Rails has `select_tag` without form.
Does phoenix has same kind of `select_tag`?

I have so many items one page then I can not make form.
So I can not use `form_for` or `select f` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Phoenix.HTML` includes [tag](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Tag.html#tag/2), [content_tag](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Tag.html#content_tag/3), [form_tag](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Tag.html#form_tag/2) and [options_for_select](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#options_for_select/2) to construct html (form) elements.

For example:

```
content_tag "select", name: "color" do
  options_for_select ["Blue": "blue", "Red": "red"], "blue"
end
```

Should render:

```
<select name="color">
  <option value="blue" selected="selected">Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

From this, you could build your own `select_tag` function.

Comment: I always did not get how to use this in eex. `                        <%= content_tag "select", name: game_type_id do %>
                           <%= options_for_select ["Red": "red", "Blue": "blue"], "blue" %>
                        <% end %>
`

Comment: I have error `(CompileError) lib/xxx/xxx/edit.html.eex:198: undefined function options_for_select/2`

Comment: You can call it like `Phoenix.HTML.Form.options_for_select` (or import the method in the view). But I've also just noted that this method was private in older versions of `phoenix_html`, so you might have to upgrade.

Comment: I got a error. `function Phoenix.HTML.Form.options_for_select/1 is undefined or private` . Sometimes works. But sometimes does not work. Please help some advise.